Tempered distribution from locally integrable function
My professor said that if a function is $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $ .
Then its associated distribution : $T_f$ is not a tempered distribution , we defined a tempered distribution as $\forall \phi \in S(\mathbb{R}) : T_f(\phi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \phi(x) dx$ .
So I thought about a counterexample which my professor doesnt understand or thinks its wrong, let $f(x) = \sin(e^{x^2} )$ this is clearly a function that has a tempered distribution $T_f$ since its absolutely continuous, so by derivative in sense of distribution $T_{f'}$ is also a tempered distribution. Then $f'(x) = 2x e^{x^2} \cos(e^{x^2})$ then $f'(x) e^{-x^2} = 2x \cos(e^{x^2}) \in L^1_{\text{loc}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $ and since $e^{-x^2} \in S(\mathbb{R})$ then $ \int_\mathbb{R} f'(x) e^{-x^2} dx $ clearly defines a tempered distribution then the RHS of the last equation also defines a tempered distribution . Is my logic flawed this is the main question of my post, infinite thanks to yall !

Silly statement. Isn't $f=0$ a counter-example?

so you mean f = 0 is a counterexample for my professor to believe it? @geetha290krm if it is then you deserve my respect hahah, but wait my professor said i want you to find me a function that isnt integrable but only $L^1_{\text{loc}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ for me to even look at your counterexample

Oh yea you are right $0 = f(x) \in L^1_{\text{loc}}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ but does that give a tempered distribution? @geetha290krm

I think your professor rather said : there exist functions in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ which are not tempered distributions ... because constants functions, gaussians, ... are tempered distributions in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$

Thank you @LL3.14 but im sure he said it clearly functions in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ cant be associated to a tempered distribution

Then it was just a mistake. By the way, your function $\sin(x^2)$ is a tempered distribution just because it is a bounded function.
